# 'gcc' failed during pandas build on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pandas, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Getting the following error when trying to install Pandas (0.16.0), which is in my requirements.txt file, on AWS Elastic Beanstalk EC2 instance:

```
  building 'pandas.msgpack' extension

  gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -D__LITTLE_ENDIAN__=1 -Ipandas/src/klib -Ipandas/src -I/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c pandas/msgpack.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/pandas/msgpack.o

  gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory

  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I'm running on `64bit Amazon Linux 2015.03 v1.3.0 running Python 2.7` and previously ran into this same error on a t1.micro instance, which was resolved when I change to a m3.medium, but I'm running an m3.xlarge so can't be a memory issue.

I have also ensured that gcc is installed as a package in `.ebextensions/00_gcc.config`:

```
packages:
   yum:
      gcc: []
      gcc-c++: []
```

Comment: Had this issue for a few days now. Rebuilding the environment and then activating x-ray and enhanced health/logging resolved this issue. Although i have no idea why there is a connection.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For pandas being compiled on Elastic Beanstalk, make sure to have both packages: `gcc-c++` *and* `python-devel`

```
packages:
   yum:
      gcc-c++: []
      python-devel: []
```

Comment: Note that the current package is "python34-devel"

Answer (score -1):

Install `python-dev`

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

For `python3`

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

Comment: can I install it in the yum packages? `python-devel: []` ?

Comment: on `centos` ==> `sudo yum install python-devel`

Answer (score -1):

on ec2 instances if you run into gcc error; try this

1. sudo yum install gcc python-setuptools python-devel postgresql-devel
2. sudo su -
3. sudo pip install

Answer (score -1):

I had to upgrade amazon's EC2 pip. You can do this by editing the .config file in .ebextensions:

`sh
commands:
  00_update_pip:
    command: "/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install --upgrade pip"`

Answer (score -1):

I solved this issue by ssh'ing in to the EBS machine and updating pip

```
pip install -U pip
```

Comment: this might not be the wisest thing to do in case the EB machine at some point terminates, since those manual changes won't persist after reboot