# elasticbeanstalk gcc and python-devel installation

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to run a flask application which has `pandas` dependency. Without having python-devel installed, pandas cannot be installed. So first I need to install gcc-c++ and python devel according to this thread: ['gcc' failed during pandas build on AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29516084/gcc-failed-during-pandas-build-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk)

Now, my `.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml` looks like:

```
branch-defaults:
  default:
    environment: flask-env
    group_suffix: null
global:
  application_name: flask-sample-app
  branch: null
  default_ec2_keyname: flask-sample-app
  default_platform: Python 3.4
  default_region: eu-west-1
  include_git_submodules: true
  instance_profile: null
  platform_name: null
  platform_version: null
  profile: null
  repository: null
  sc: null
  workspace_type: Application
packages:
  yum:
    gcc-c++: []
    python-devel: []
```

But after successful `eb deploy` command, I connect to it via `eb ssh` and see that it wasn't installed. Is my config.yml correct?

Comment: YAML files are very sensitive to whitespace, and your `packages` section looks like it's using three-space indents while the other sections are using two-space indents...might be a problem. You can also look at `/var/log/eb-activity.log` to see if there are any informative log messages.

Comment: ahh yes, I fixed the indentation problem, but still not being installed. should I do something addition to eb deploy after changing the config file? I'm currently not using git system, just trying to figure out the elasticbeanstalk.

Comment: `eb deploy` should be all that's needed. Can you post your `/var/log/eb-activity.log`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I created a yaml file in `.ebextensions` instead of `.elasticbeanstalk`, it worked. I was simply putting the yaml file under the wrong directory.

.elasticbeanstalk/pandas.yml:

```
packages:
  yum:
    gcc-c++: []
    python3?-devel.x*: []
```

I got error while trying to install `python-devel: []`:

> Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Yum does not have python-devel available for installation

So the correct devel package name, in my case, is either 'python27-devel.x86_64' or 'python35-devel.x86_64'

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=233268

[How to install python3-devel on red hat 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43047284/how-to-install-python3-devel-on-red-hat-7)

Answer (score 0):

Pandas and NumPy seem to give the most trouble whatever way you go to deploy something. I haven't used elastic-beanstalk myself but have done it direct on servers and in docker.

Can see one difference with what you have and what worked for me. I think you need both gcc and g++ as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37496714/4288043)

So perhaps add a line before those last lines of yours:

```
packages:
  yum:
    gcc: []
    gcc-c++: []
    python-devel: []
```

Am just translating accross what worked in another area.