# AWS beanstalk cant install psycopg2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pip, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have issues deploying my Django application to AWS in the free tier during the pip installation of my requirements.txt.

As I could see here the issue seems to be related to scipy:

[AWS Elastic Beanstalk failed to install Python package using requirements.txt Git Pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48334158/aws-elastic-beanstalk-failed-to-install-python-package-using-requirements-txt-gi)

The question has been resolved as he could uppgrade to t2.medium but this requires a paid account.
Is there any tip for the free tier?

Could an option like '--no-cache-dir' make it work ? Is there a way to force it (as the pip install is automatically done)

*Is there any other way to deploy a Django application on AWS ?*

**EDIT**: It is actually because of psycopg2..

> Collecting psycopg2==2.8.4 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 4))
>
> Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/84/d7/6a93c99b5ba4d4d22daa3928b983cec66df4536ca50b22ce5dcac65e4e71/psycopg2-2.8.4.tar.gz (377kB)
>
> Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>
> running egg_info
>
> creating pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info
>
> writing pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
>
> writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
>
> writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
>
> writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
>
> /usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'project_urls'
>
> warnings.warn(msg)
>
> warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found
>
> Error: pg_config executable not found.
>
> pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
>
> containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
>
> option:
>
> python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...
>
> or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

Comment: Let's take a step back. Nothing here shows us that you're having the same issue as what's in the linked question. What does "I have issues" mean? What is the exact error message that you're seeing, with traceback? See [ask].

Comment: Sorry let me add my error message

Comment: Ok I am very sorry, just understood how to check the logs, it fails before that !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+Error%3A+pg_config+executable+not+found

Comment: The package [psycopg2-binary](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2-binary/) has a lot of precompiled binary wheels. Try `pip install psycopg2-binary` (or add it to `requirements.txt` instead of `psycopg2`).

Comment: thank you very much for your help, still not working yet but at least this step is done!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per @phd comment : `pip install psycopg2-binary` did the trick instead of `pip install psycopg2`

Answer (score 2):

Although I like the simplicity of the accepted solution, the `psycopg2-binary` [installation notes](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2-binary/) advise against using it for production:

> The binary package is a practical choice for development and testing but in production it is advised to use the package built from sources.

I don't know if this really is a big issue, but, for the sake of completeness, I'll add an alternative:

The `Error: pg_config executable not found.` can also be fixed by installing `postgresql-devel` using `yum`.

On Amazon Linux 2 you could do this using `.platform` [hooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html). For example, in you app repository (next to your `.ebextensions`), add a `.platform/hooks/prebuild/01_install_yum_packages.sh` file with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
yum -y install postgresql-devel
```

As described in the docs, you have to set execution permissions on this file before committing it to you repo. E.g. `chmod +x 01_install_yum_packages.sh`.